# Drop down issue in ie 11

Tags: c#, asp.net, drop-down-menu, internet-explorer-11

I have a asp.net  drop down that loads over 20,000+ records .It was working fine ie8 but when upgraded to ie11 the drop down gets stuck and any attempt to re-size the browser will crash the browser.(I cant split the values and add it to other drop downs).Is there a way to handle this.

Comment: Just curious, does it work fine if your run it in Compatibility View?

Comment: Do you have all updates installed for IE11?  There was a known bug where dropdowns could crash the tab: https://connect.microsoft.com/IE/feedback/details/806679/ie-11-desktop-selecting-an-item-from-a-drop-down-list-on-a-webpage-causes-the-tab-to-crash

Comment: It does not work fine in Compatibility View. I think that bug was pretty old one, I think i have all the ie 11 updates